# Laravel switching from MySQL to MSSQL

Tags: laravel-5

I'm currently developing a web apps for my client, and my development server (a shared hosting server) only support MySql. But I just came to know that my client on whose server I'm going to deploy the laravel web apps on only support Mssql.

So my question is, later when I deploy the laravel web app on my client's server, what should I do to make the web apps works perfectly well? Is it enough if I just change the default driver from `mysql` to `sqlsrv`?

Comment: If you don't use MySQL-specific raw expressions in your code, changing the driver should theoretically be enough. But I *strongly* recommend that you find a way to test the application on SQL Server before deploying it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @JonasStaudenmeir but can you give me an example of mysql-specific raw expression?

Comment: MySQL uses backticks to quote column/table names, SQL Server uses square brackets. So ``select(DB::raw('sum(`column`)'))`` would work on MySQL but not on SQL Server. You would have to use an unquoted column name (if possible): ``select(DB::raw('sum(column)'))``

Comment: There are also database features in Laravel that are not implemented for SQL Server.

Comment: I see.. thanks a lot @JonasStaudenmeir for your comments